# Yii2 Render an image in DetailView

Tags: yii2

I am trying to render an Image in view file. My code is like below:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'name',
            //'photo',
            [
                'attribute'=>'photo',
                'value'=>('<img src =' .'uploads/' . $model->photo . ' height="100" width="100"' .   '>')
            ],


            [
                'attribute' => 'birth_date',
                'format' => ['date', 'dd-MM-Y'],
                        ],  
        'mobile',
            ],

    ]) ?>
```

Though the code below works:

```
<?php echo ('<img src =' .'uploads/' . $model->photo .'>'); ?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this:

```
[
    'attribute'=>'photo',
    'value'=>$model->photo,
    'format' => ['image',['width'=>'100','height'=>'100']],
],
```

Comment: Hi Ali, I have tried the code exactly as given and with the variation
`'value'=>\yii\helpers\Html::img('<img src =' .'uploads/' . $model->photo .'>',['width'=>'100','height'=>'100']),`

But it's not working.

Comment: @Pawan I'm sorry, I forgot to add img source :) Try again with new edit on my answer.

Comment: I have used the edited code, but still unsuccessful. In place of the image I am getting: 
`<img src="uploads/Lighthouse.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="">`

Comment: Hi Ali, still no luck. With the edited code, it is blank, where I was getting that code.
May be something is still missing.

Comment: @Pawan Now, everything is working fine. If you take a look at the source of generated details view you can see the img tag. But, it seems the path of image is not correct. Please try to check whether `uploads/Lighthouse.jpg` is valid or not.

Comment: Hi Ali, the path is absolutely correct, as I have checked your code outside of the array it is working perfect. only inside array it's not rendering the image.
for example:
`<?php $a=\yii\helpers\Html::img('uploads/' . $model->photo,['width'=>'100','height'=>'100']);
    echo $a;`

Comment: I have inspected the code with firebug - there is some problem - as the code shown in firebug - the code generated is like this -

`<img alt="" src="<img src="uploads/Koala.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="">">`

why it is happening like that?

Comment: Well :)) check edit please, there were a mistake. Sorry about that :)

Comment: Hi Ali, Now it is rendering the image perfectly, 

but resizing is still not working.

Comment: how can i add anchor tag wrapped on image.

Comment: please help i want if when its empty will result `-` when i using format like that its make have img when its empty too `strlen($model->photo) !== 0 ? ? $model->photo  : '-'`  any idea? @AliMasudianPour

Answer (score 4):

```
 DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'photo:image',
        ],
    ])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[
 'attribute'=>'group_pic',
'value'=>('uploads/group_pro_pic/' . $model->group_pic),
'format' => ['image',['width'=>'230','height'=>'200']],
            ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[
   'attribute'=>'images',
   'value'=> Yii::$app->homeUrl.'uploads/'.$model->images,
   'format' => ['image',['width'=>'100','height'=>'100']],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[
  'attribute' => 'vUpload',
  'value'=>'uploads/' .$model->vUpload,
  'format' => ['image',['width'=>'100','height'=>'100']],
],
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[
    'attribute'=>'profile',
    'value'=>'../uploads/' .$model->profile,
    'format' => ['image',['width'=>'100','height'=>'100']],
],
```