# image are not shown in admin in yii 2.0

Tags: php, yii2

I want to show images instead of image name in admin panel. but i got many examples in yii 1.1 but not understanding to use in yii 2.0.
 here is my grid view

```
   <?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\imagine\Image;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Contents');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="content-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Create Content'), ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'id',
            'label',
            'title',
            'content',
        /*  ['attribute' => 'main_image',
                'header' => 'Image',
                'value' => function( $data ) {

                return ?><img src="<?= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl ?>/upload/content/<?php echo $data->main_image?>">
            <?php
           }
           ],*/

                [
                'attribute'=>'photo',
                'value' =>  Html::a(Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/upload/content'.$content->main_image, ['alt'=>'some', 'class'=>'thing', 'height'=>'100px', 'width'=>'100px']), ['site/zoom']),
                'format' => ['raw'],
                ],



            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>

</div>
```

I am getting error of undefined content,and  I also tried the above code which are in comment. but it show 'not set' in filed list.

if any idea about that pls help...

Answer (score 1):

You should format your attribute this way  (hoping the path are correct)

```
       ['attribute' => 'main_image',
            'header' => 'Image',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function( $model ) {
                return '<img src="' . echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . '/upload/content/'. $model->main_image .'">' ;
       }
    ],
```

Comment: please .. tell me if there are error or what is show .. .. evntually check with var_dump the fucntion result and adjust your path ..

Comment: sir i get the solution but can i use the same code  to show images in view.php  file?

Comment: @vikash. view require bit different style. Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896529/yii2-render-an-image-in-detailview

Answer (score 0):

I get the solution using this code

```
   ['attribute' => 'main_image',
                    'header' => 'Image',
                    'format' => ['raw'],
                    'value' => function( $data ) {

                    return Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/upload/content/'.$data->main_image, ['alt'=>'some', 'class'=>'thing', 'height'=>'100px', 'width'=>'100px']);

               }
               ],
```